# Recuperar datos de Realtime Database android

Tags: android, firebase

Quiero obtener un String con addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(), y usarlo fuera de este metodo, en cualquier otro sitio de la app.
Por ejemplo el valor de "nombre"

```
String nombre;
bbdd = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Usuarios/"); //Antes "Fichas"
        bbdd.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                DataSnapshot snapshot = dataSnapshot.child(miIDusuario); // Selecciona en un nodo concreto
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    UsuariosPojo usuarios = snapshot.getValue(UsuariosPojo.class);
                    nombre = usuarios.getNombre();
                    textNombre.setText(nombre); // Aqui nombre funciona bien, pero fuera de aqui no tiene ningun valor
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: El problema es que las llamadas a Firebase son asíncronas, por tanto no es seguro que las variables que llenas dentro de los métodos de Firebase tengan el valor que esperas cuando intentas usarlas fuera. Hay varias formas de solucionar esto: 1. declarando la variable como miembro de la clase, asignándola dentro del método de Firebase y luego llamando a otro método donde querrías usar la variable; 2. Creando un callback mediante interfaces; 3. Aplicando *Componentes de Arquitectura* que usa el estilo MVVM con  `LiveData` (esto sería lo recomendable, porque es hacia donde va Android).

Comment: Sobre el punto 3, que es lo más recomendable porque tiene varias ventajas, te dejo dos entradas publicadas en el blog de Firebase donde se explica con un ejemplo cómo implementar código basado  en *Componentes de Arquitectura de Android*, usando Firebase. Allí se explica también cuáles son las ventajas. [Parte 1](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/12/using-android-architecture-components.html)  y [Parte 2](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/12/using-android-architecture-components_20.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es crear un `interface`, pasarla como parámetro y cuando recibas el nombre, simplemente llamas la función del `interface`.

```
interface NameListener {
   public void onName(String name);
}


public void listenToName(NameListener listener) {

    bbdd = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Usuarios/"); //Antes "Fichas"
    bbdd.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = dataSnapshot.child(miIDusuario); // Selecciona en un nodo concreto
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                UsuariosPojo usuarios = snapshot.getValue(UsuariosPojo.class);
                String nombre = usuarios.getNombre();
                // textNombre.setText(nombre); // Aqui nombre funciona bien, pero fuera de aqui no tiene ningun valor
                listener.onName(nombre);
            }
        }
        
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}



public void getNombre() {
    
    listenToName(new NameListener() {

        @Override
        public void onName(String name) {
            // usa name como gustes
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: estas dando una respuesta de la que no sabes si tiene errores?

Comment: Syntax es correcto. Lo acabo de confirmar. El código o mi idea es una de las mil soluciones que pueden existir. Para la próxima procuraré de confirmar syntax especialmente en Java ya que no lo he usado en los últimos 4-5 años.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que he encontrado una forma mas sencilla. No se si es muy correcta pero lo pongo porque me funciona bien y por si le sirve a alguien.
Defino la variable que quiero como static String usuario;
En la clase Pojo, en set pongo la variable que quiero.
En el codigo de Firebase uso el setNombre de Pojo y me quedo la variable que quiero y ya puedo usarla con normalidad

```
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    Nombre = nombre;
    MiClase.usuario = nombre;
    }

    bbdd = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Usuarios/"); //Antes "Fichas"
bbdd.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        DataSnapshot snapshot = dataSnapshot.child(miIDusuario); // Selecciona en un nodo concreto
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            UsuariosPojo usuarios = snapshot.getValue(UsuariosPojo.class);
            String nombre = usuarios.getNombre();
            usuarios.setNombre(nombre); // Aqui consigo la global usuario y ya la puedo usar con normalidad
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
```